Using 'quill editor' in Vue3 vite, data model cannot be bound（Beginner in front-end development）
Here is my code case study：

dependencies

   "dependencies": {
   "@vueup/vue-quill": "^1.2.0",
   "element-plus": "^2.6.3",
   "quill": "^1.3.7",
   "vue": "^3.4.21"

2.index.vue(path[src/compents/Editor/index.vue])
<template>
  <div>
    <el-upload
        :action="uploadFileUrl"
        :before-upload="handleBeforeUpload"
        :on-success="handleUploadSuccess"
        :on-error="handleUploadError"
        name="file"
        :show-file-list="false"
        :headers="headers"
        style="display: none"
        ref="upload"
        v-if="this.type === 'url'"
    >
    </el-upload>
    <div class="editor" ref="editor" :style="styles"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Quill from "quill";
import "quill/dist/quill.core.css";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  props: {
    /* 编辑器的内容 */
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    /* 高度 */
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
    /* 最小高度 */
    minHeight: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
    /* 只读 */
    readOnly: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    // 上传文件大小限制(MB)
    fileSize: {
      type: Number,
      default: 5,
    },
    /* 类型（base64格式、url格式） */
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "url",
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      uploadFileUrl: "/admin-api/infra/file/upload", // 请求地址
      Quill: null,
      currentValue: "",
      options: {
        theme: "snow",
        bounds: document.body,
        debug: "warn",
        modules: {
          // 工具栏配置
          toolbar: [
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],       // 加粗 斜体 下划线 删除线
            ["blockquote", "code-block"],                    // 引用  代码块
            [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],       // 有序、无序列表
            [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }],            // 缩进
            [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],   // 字体大小
            [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],         // 标题
            [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],             // 字体颜色、字体背景颜色
            [{ align: [] }],                                 // 对齐方式
            ["clean"],                                       // 清除文本格式
            ["link", "image", "video"]                       // 链接、图片、视频
          ],
        },
        placeholder: "请输入内容",
        readOnly: this.readOnly,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styles() {
      let style = {};
      if (this.minHeight) {
        style.minHeight = `${this.minHeight}px`;
      }
      if (this.height) {
        style.height = `${this.height}px`;
      }
      return style;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(val) {
        if (val !== this.currentValue) {
          this.currentValue = val === null ? "" : val;
          if (this.Quill) {
            this.Quill.pasteHTML(this.currentValue);
          }
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.Quill = null;
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      const editor = this.$refs.editor;
      this.Quill = new Quill(editor, this.options);
      // 如果设置了上传地址则自定义图片上传事件
      if (this.type === 'url') {
        let toolbar = this.Quill.getModule("toolbar");
        toolbar.addHandler("image", (value) => {
          this.uploadType = "image";
          if (value) {
            this.$refs.upload.$children[0].$refs.input.click();
          } else {
            this.quill.format("image", false);
          }
        });
      }
      this.Quill.pasteHTML(this.currentValue);
      this.Quill.on("text-change", (delta, oldDelta, source) => {
        const html = this.$refs.editor.children[0].innerHTML;
        const text = this.Quill.getText();
        const quill = this.Quill;
        this.currentValue = html;
        this.$emit("input", html);
        this.$emit("on-change", { html, text, quill });
      });
      this.Quill.on("text-change", (delta, oldDelta, source) => {
        this.$emit("on-text-change", delta, oldDelta, source);
      });
      this.Quill.on("selection-change", (range, oldRange, source) => {
        this.$emit("on-selection-change", range, oldRange, source);
      });
      this.Quill.on("editor-change", (eventName, ...args) => {
        this.$emit("on-editor-change", eventName, ...args);
      });
    },
    // 上传前校检格式和大小
    handleBeforeUpload(file) {
      // 校检文件大小
      if (this.fileSize) {
        const isLt = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < this.fileSize;
        if (!isLt) {
          this.$message.error(`上传文件大小不能超过 ${this.fileSize} MB!`);
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
    handleUploadSuccess(res, file) {
      // 获取富文本组件实例
      let quill = this.Quill;
      // 如果上传成功
      // edit by 力源科技
      if (res.code === 200 || res.code === 0) {
        // 获取光标所在位置
        let length = quill.getSelection().index;
        // 插入图片  res.url为服务器返回的图片地址
        // edit by 力源科技
        quill.insertEmbed(length, "image", res.data);
        // 调整光标到最后
        quill.setSelection(length + 1);
      } else {
        this.$message.error("图片插入失败");
      }
    },
    handleUploadError() {
      this.$message.error("图片插入失败");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.editor, .ql-toolbar {
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  line-height: normal !important;
}
.quill-img {
  display: none;
}
.ql-snow .ql-tooltip[data-mode="link"]::before {
  content: "请输入链接地址:";
}
.ql-snow .ql-tooltip.ql-editing a.ql-action::after {
  border-right: 0px;
  content: "保存";
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.ql-snow .ql-tooltip[data-mode="video"]::before {
  content: "请输入视频地址:";
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item::before {
  content: "14px";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label[data-value="small"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value="small"]::before {
  content: "10px";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label[data-value="large"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value="large"]::before {
  content: "18px";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label[data-value="huge"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value="huge"]::before {
  content: "32px";
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item::before {
  content: "文本";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="1"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="1"]::before {
  content: "标题1";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="2"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="2"]::before {
  content: "标题2";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="3"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="3"]::before {
  content: "标题3";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="4"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="4"]::before {
  content: "标题4";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="5"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="5"]::before {
  content: "标题5";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="6"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="6"]::before {
  content: "标题6";
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item::before {
  content: "标准字体";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value="serif"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value="serif"]::before {
  content: "衬线字体";
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value="monospace"]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value="monospace"]::before {
  content: "等宽字体";
}
</style>


main.js

import "./assets/main.css";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import ElementPlus from "element-plus";
import "element-plus/dist/index.css";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount("#app");


HomeVue.vue

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Editor from "@/components/Editor/index.vue";



const editorContent = ref({
    title: '',
    content: ''
})



const printData = () => {
    console.log('11111->' + editorContent.value.title)
    console.log('22222->' + editorContent.value.content)
}
`your text`
const clearData = () => {
        editorContent.value.title = ''
        editorContent.value.content = ''

}
</script>
<template>
    <el-form :model="editorContent" label-width="100px">
        <el-form-item label="测试标题">
            <el-input v-model="editorContent.title" placeholder="请输入标题"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item label="富文本">
            <div>
                <Editor v-model:value="editorContent.content"/>
            </div>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
            <el-button type="primary" @click="printData">提交</el-button>
            <el-button type="info" @click="clearData">重置</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
</template>

4.App.vue
<script setup>
import HomeVue from '@/vues/HomeVue.vue';
import EditorTestVue from './vues/EditorTest.vue';

</script>

<template>
  <HomeVue/>
</template>


I made the following attempts:
According to the retrieved pre solution, add or modify the attribute 'v mode' 'or': value='', 'v mode: content=' 'in the<Editor/>tag. After starting the project, enter' title 'in the input box on the page, enter' titletest 'in the rich text editor, and click the submit button and reset button. At the same time, open the console panel of the browser. The result of the submit button is as result 1; The result of the reset button is as shown in result 2

Result 1:
11111->title
22222->

Result 2:
11111->
22222->


My expected outcome:
When the page is loaded, my editorContent.titl attribute value is loaded in the input box, and my editorContent.content is displayed in the rich text box,
After clicking submit, my content can be assigned values by the rich text box content. After clicking the reset button, I clear the values of my data model, and both the input box and rich text box content are cleared simultaneously, achieving the same data bidirectional binding effect as the input box


I think Quill does not have good Vue 3 compatibility/support. Have you tried TinyMCE or TipTap ?

I have received your message and I will try to use the TinyMCE and TipTap you mentioned. Thank you very much

@anshink No lib has good Vue support if it wasn't designed specifically for Vue. This is the reason why there are additional wrappers for frameworks like vueup/vue-quill. You don't seem to use it at all.

@Estus Flask
Thank you for answering my question. I'm sorry that I didn't post all the Quill version test samples. I have made progress using Tinymec and it can effectively solve the problem of bidirectional binding of data models. Thank you again for your answer

My point is it's low-effort trial and error at this point, not the best strategy to choose a lib . There's no fundamental problem with Quill afaik that would make it less preferable than tinymce with vue. I'd suggest to pick an editor that primarily suits your needs feature-wise

@Estus Flask Okay. Thank you so much for your advice

You can use a tiny wrapper component to build the editor with Quill 2 and Vue 3:
npm add quill@2.0.0 vue-quilly
# Or
pnpm add quill@2.0.0 vue-quilly

import Quill from 'quill' // Full build
import Quill from 'quill/core' // Core build
import { QuillyEditor } from 'vue-quilly'

Add core styles. Also import one of Quill's themes, if you need one:
import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css' // Required
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css' // For snow theme (optional)
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css' // For bubble theme (optional)

Define Quill options:
const options = {
  theme: 'snow', // If you need Quill theme
  modules: {
    toolbar: true,
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  readOnly: false
}

Initialize the editor:
const editor = ref<InstanceType<typeof QuillyEditor>>()
const model = ref<string>('<p>Hello Quilly!</p>')
// Quill instance
let quill: Quill | null = null
onMounted(() => {
  quill = editor.value?.initialize(Quill)!
})

<QuillyEditor
  ref="editor"
  v-model="model"
  :options="options"
  @text-change="({ delta, oldContent, source }) => console.log('text-change', delta, oldContent, source)"
  @selection-change="({ range, oldRange, source }) => console.log('selection-change', range, oldRange, source)"
  @editor-change="(eventName) => console.log('editor-change', `eventName: ${eventName}`)"
  @focus="(quill) => console.log('focus', quill)"
  @blur="(quill) => console.log('blur', quill)"
  @ready="(quill) => console.log('ready', quill)"
/>

Use v-model for HTML content type. You can set content in Delta format using Quill instance:
quill?.setContents(
  new Delta()
    .insert('Hello')
    .insert('\n', { header: 1 })
    .insert('Some ')
    .insert('initial', { bold: true })
    .insert(' ')
    .insert('content', { underline: true })
    .insert('\n')
)

Creating editors with QullyEditor demo

I'm very sorry for taking so long to reply you. My problem is solved. Thank you very much for your answer.

Quill does not have support for Vue, but you can use JS in vue. You can listen to the "text-change" event of the Quill editor to update the value of your variable. See the code below where this has been implemented.
https://codepen.io/Wimmie13/pen/GRLQwoz
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="editorElement" style="min-height: 150px" />
    <div>
      <strong>Current value is:</strong>
      {{ value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Quill from "https://esm.sh/quill";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const value = ref("<h3>This is my title</h3><p>Some content</p>");
const editorElement = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  // Set the content for the editor
  editorElement.value.innerHTML = value.value;

  // Create the Quill editor
  const quill = new Quill(editorElement.value, {
    bounds: ".content-wrapper",
    modules: {
      toolbar: true
    },
    theme: "snow"
  });

  // Set the quill content to the value variable
  quill.on("text-change", function () {
    value.value = quill.root.innerHTML;
  });
});
</script>

<style>
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quill@1.3.7/dist/quill.base.css";
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quill@1.3.7/dist/quill.snow.css";
</style>


I'm very sorry for taking so long to reply you. My problem is solved. Thank you very much for your answer.
